# Python scapy error

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to import scapy , but I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip2.py", line 17, in <module>
    ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst = ips), timeout = 2, iface=interface, inter = 0.1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 378, in srp
    a,b=sndrcv(s ,x,*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\compatibility.py", line 14, in sndrcv
    if not isinstance(pkt, Gen):
NameError: global name 'Gen' is not defined
```

These are the imports :

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from scapy.base_classes import Gen, SetGen
from scapy.utils import PcapReader
from scapy.data import MTU, ETH_P_ARP
```

I have tried everything I could find online. Nothing helps.
I am using windows 10 , and I have the latest version of scapy. I have no idea where this error came from or what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Writing at the start of program:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

Before:

```
from scapy.base_classes import Gen, SetGen
from scapy.utils import PcapReader
from scapy.data import MTU, ETH_P_ARP
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

> There are some missing imports. You can add
>
> ```
> from scapy.base_classes import Gen, SetGen 
> import scapy.plist as plist
> from scapy.utils import PcapReader 
> from scapy.data import MTU, ETH_P_ARP
> ```
>
> **to the beggining of the scapy/arch/windows/compatibility.py file until it is fixed**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

[source](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/312)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

This will import everything from scapy into your script.